# If there are any curve databases with structured data

Tags: curves, data-mining

I found these curve *lists*:

- http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_curves
- http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Curves/Curves.html
- http://old.nationalcurvebank.org/home/home.htm
- http://www.2dcurves.com/
- http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/courbes2d.shtml

But they aren't very structured. Wondering if there is anything with on the order of thousands of highly structured curves.

Comment: Please define **in your question** what you mean by "structured curves" and why the curve lists you mentioned fail according to your definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by structured, you mean listed in categories of similar types. My standard references in that regard are

*A Catalog of Special Plane Curves*, J. Dennis Lawrence, Dover, 1972

*CRC Standard Curves and Surfaces*, David von Seggern, CRC Press, 1993.

And some auxiliary references

*Gnomon: from Pharoahs to fractals*, Michael J. Gazal$\acute{\text{e}}$, Princeton University Press, 1999

*Spiral: from Theodorus to Chaos*, Philip J. Davis, A.K. Peters, Ltd., 1993.