# Equation for an asymptotically flat spiral

Tags: parametric

I would like to find an expression of a spiral which gets straight at infinity, as in the image below:

[image]

so that I can make a parametric plot.

Comment: One natural approach is a polar graph $r = f(\theta)$ with a "first-order" asymptote, such as $f(\theta) = (1/\theta) + e^{-\theta}$ for $\theta < 0$.

Comment: I feel confident that there's a positive answer to your question, but am unable to access my references due to their still being boxed up from a recent move. However, a previous answer I gave contains these titles: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117027/if-there-are-any-curve-databases-with-structured-data/3117754#3117754,